# Are answers which merely summarize other answers acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers

Maybe this has already been discussed before, but I couldn't find any relevant question here.

I recently found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21396837/1636285) which appears to do nothing but summarize other answers. The user merely took the existing answers, changed the URLs used in the example codes, and removed any explanation. And while he did add some “original” pieces of code into his answer, those are unfortunately just wrong and completely miss the question (cf. `window.history.back()` when the question is about redirecting).

For future reference, here's a screenshot of the answer (in case it gets removed):

> [image: screenshot of the answer in question]

I personally find such answers terribly useless, since the other answers were posted years ago, and it doesn't add anything to them.

However, seeing the vote counts makes me doubt that it is a completely useless answer -- it seems to be a pretty popular answer with much more upvotes than downvotes. So maybe it *did* help some users after all… but I still think that it belongs more in a blog post than in an answer.

Is it acceptable to post answers which merely summarize other answers?

Bonus question: what if such a “summary answer” had some extra, useful content in addition to the summary?

Comment: According to this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70619/may-i-summarize-all-answers) it is fine to summarize all answers in another answer.

Comment: It really depends. The example presented by the OP doesn't feel to me like it adds any value. I downvoted it.

Comment: Wow, that's a horrible answer. "*Here's a bunch of code snippets, try which one works for you*". Including worst practises.

Comment: I don't understand the number of upvotes it has got!

Comment: Me neither… maybe it has to do with the fact that the question is a very popular one? But still, such a high number of upvotes for such a terrible answer…

Comment: That particular answer probably got a lot of upvotes from users finding it via google as it _does_ solve their problem, despite not meeting our standards as a good answer.

Comment: It is not uncommon for people to find a popular question, look over the answers, and then copy one of them and submit it as another answer. Easy rep.

Comment: I've tried to create helpful summary answers before, and I always give credit to the answers I use. Even so, they seem to get a fairly mixed reception, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28909742/1858225 or (on SuperUser) http://superuser.com/a/699991/199803

Comment: @Bergi: That's not even the best part. The best part is that the *answerer* himself doesn't even seem all that confident of any of them. The typical "may be this helps you" statement you so often see in uncertain answers. Makes you wonder why they bothered. (Then again, obviously it paid off with all those upvotes...)

Comment: @IanRingrose a lot of times if there is a one line code answer that is (or seems) correct but offers no further information other than some code vs answer with an explanation with what the line is, why you'd want it as well as supporting link to documentation, the first one gets more upvotes. A lot of people don't want to read. Middling answers attract more votes than excellent ones: [The problem with extrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Summaries *can* be ok if they add a new concise viewpoint to what is a bunch of complicated answers, for example, or when they add a specific argument why one of the answers is better than the other.

Mere copy & paste summaries like this one, however, are bad and should be downvoted. Perhaps even removal is warranted, given that it's basically a code only answer with no context.

- They add no new information and no new viewpoint.
- They are difficult to keep updated. Who is going to update the summary if one of the answers turns out to contain a security flaw? That's right, nobody.
- They make it impossible for the community to vote on separate approaches, and comment on issues with them.

Summaries like this one are really antithetical to the Stack Overflow Q&A model.

Comment: If I were posting a summary-only answer which was just a roundup of other answers, in the *rare* case where that could be useful, I'd mark it was what it was: A community wiki. Not doing so would feel very, very wrong.

Comment: Voting for this to be deleted. Otherwise it is super straight forward just to search for a highly upvoted popular questions and to write my own copypaste to get upvotes.

Comment: @SalvadorDali agreed, this answer should be marked for deletion. Tried to do this,  unfortunately the low quality option is not available (probably due to the number of upvotes), and none of the other options seem to apply. What can I do in this case? :)

Answer (score 5):

The given question clearly **needs** a great summary answer that explains the pro and cons of each option, along with sample codes and a list of the browsers that each option has been tested in.

The linked answer is clearly of little use to anyone and I fail to understand why it has got any up votes.   But I am not happy with it just being deleted, as so many people have upvoted it.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/1636285) should work almost universally, except that it empties the Referrer header on IE8 and lower. This is mentioned in the answer's comments, and there's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690095/1636285) with a solution for this. Maybe that information should be edited into the accepted answer?

Comment: @LéoLam given the number of views, the accepted answer should be made a good as possible and be standalone.   This should be done by an expert, e.g. not me!

Answer (score 4):

> Are answers which merely summarize other answers acceptable?

I disagree.  Mere summarization does little to add to the answers given and a similar effect could be achieved by users who peruse the given answers.

On the other hand, if the given answers are all somewhat useful but offer different approaches to solving the problem in a disjointed way (meaning it is hard to tell the differences between them or advantages/disadvantages) I would be grateful to see a post that takes relevant information and inspiration from the given answers and not only summarizes the idea behind each one but relates them to each other and expounds as appropriate with examples that can be compared easily.  That would be the ideal "summary answer" and when done right I believe it would add to StackOverflow.