# When is it cool to summarize answers in question edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions, writing-style

Sometimes a question may attract a large number of answers, and often many of those answers are equally or at least similarly "correct", just for different use cases, etc.  I recently found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9463318/1586231), in which the OP edited their original question after selecting an answer to reflect a concise summary of the various existing answers.

In that case, **it was really useful**: this sort of summary answer in the question edit **got me to the information I wanted very quickly**.  But obviously in cases like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6040583/1586231), where some of the answers are a bit longer, trying to summarize the answers in an edit to the question would probably decrease readability.

So when is it, if ever, appropriate and indeed correct to edit your question to include a summary of the correct answers below?  Is there some on-the-books rule about this?  Or is it just a matter of personal taste?

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11979111/1586231) is one of the first questions I ever asked on Stack Overflow.  I could easily edit my question to say something like:

> **Here is the gist of the below answers**: 1. You can jailbreak the device, 2. You can .. etc

What do you think?

Comment: actually i believe that edit should not have been made. it was my understanding that questions should not be edited to contain answers. infact App Work's edits have been rolled back several times and even [noted not to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9463318/12). i have flagged the question for a mod to do the rollback and edit lock to prevent the OP doing it again

Comment: @Memor-X would you say it's appropriate in some very unique instances? For example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is a very unusual answer, and I totally support it being the way it is, despite our general standards of formality.

Comment: (To be clear, I wouldn't add a summary to the question I link to in my above comment, I just mean to illustrate that I think there are times when the rules are better bent.  And I'm wondering if summaries in question edits are an example of a rule that in some cases should be bent, or if that's more of a concrete rule that should be respected.)

Comment: to edit the question with the answer my understanding was generally no. there are some cases like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/1028804) but it was created to be a sort of index for questions from day 1 rather than an edit after an answer (because a question *"what do all the symbols mean in PHP"* i think is too broad)

Comment: That's super interesting - not just because it breaks some common rules, but also because it's almost a sort of precursor to SO Documentation.  I still think that that example is best kept as is, as sort of a historical document, even if Documentation eventually contains all that information.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IMHO it is *never* cool to summarize answers into questions. Questions should be used for, well, of course, *questions*, and answers for answers to the question. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103154/should-an-appended-answer-within-a-question-be-moved) is an old discussion about this topic.

Summarizing answers *can* be useful, but has its own [disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300587/4751173), maintainability being the worst problem if you ask me. What if a new version of Postgres breaks one of the options? That needs to be edited into both the answer and the question. [DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is one of my pet peeves in programming, and it also applies to Q&A sites like Stack Overflow.

Comment: The summary-idea always reminds me of the classic "competing standards" [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/). There are 14 answers, lets summarize them. Result: there are now 15 answers.