# Is it all right to combine 2 answers to create only one answer?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

Browsing Stack Overflow today, I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776270/android-service-vs-activity/43776378#43776378) which has an answer that literally combines 2 other answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517793/whats-the-difference-between-activity-and-service), the only addition being a link to read more about the problem. Now, the question is whether this is considered plagiarism, or is a good way to improve the answers (although I read on Meta that the copy paste of answers is not really encouraged)?

Comment: You certainly don't get _less_ plagiarism by adding plagiarism together.

Comment: related/dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300586/are-answers-which-merely-summarize-other-answers-acceptable/300678#300678

Comment: The linked posts in your question are not a good example, as they should be closed and not answered. But in general, copy-paste two answers won't be much helpful. However, you can add your own explanation and conclusions while quoting (and linking) the original posts.

Comment: The plagiarized answer didn't even add the link to read more, it was in the original answer from the other question.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't look like he combined two answers from ther previous question, he simply copied the first answer almost verbatim. The only change was that he added a little wording before the link to the developer.android.com site.

Comment: This is actually a tricky question, because in the early days of Stack Overflow, there was this idea that we wanted canonical answers. That is, each question would have One Best Answer, and if the answer really is as good as possible, then in principle it could stand up as the question's Only Answer. And the only way to do that in the face of multiple *good* answers would be to (potentially) incorporate all the best stuff from other answers in one super-answer. Yes, it would have to add value beyond just being a copy-paste job. But borrowing/aggregating *was* encouraged at one point.

Comment: Just to finish off my previous comment, I could have sworn I read something by Jeff Atwood or Joel Spolsky to that effect.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not encouraged.

If it's a verbatim copy of another answer without attribution, and the answer has no value of its own if you remove all the copy-pasted stuff:

- Flag for moderator attention (custom flag, "plagiarism from...")
- Add a comment explaining that copying & pasting without attribution is not encouraged on Stack Overflow, and that they should add content of their own even when using other people's work as reference. Posting [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) can help.

Especially with new members, it's important to comment *politely*. Chances are they didn't mean any harm; there are different attitudes toward plagiarism across cultures.

On the other hand, if you feel like a bit of plagiarism-hunting, where there is one instance of plagiarism, there's often more. [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) a FAQ page with helpful tips what to do when discovering plagiarism.

If the case is less clear - for example, the answer still adds value even if you remove all the plagiarized content - you can fix the situation by yourself by editing in a reference, replacing the copied content by a link, and/or adding a comment giving the author advice for the future.

Comment: You shouldn't really be commenting on posts like this at all.  It's the moderators' job to handle the situation; let them.

Comment: Maybe if we stopped calling it "plagiarism" and started calling it "stealing", these people from "other cultures" would finally understand that this behaviour is not acceptable.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: You can certainly make a case that it's possible to "steal" something from someone without actually depriving them of it -- the RIAA and MPAA have been making that case for years, with mixed success -- but simply *calling* it "stealing" is not likely to be sufficient to convince someone that your culture's perspective is superior to theirs.

Comment: @ruakh: *shrug* Not convinced. I think it sounds stronger all around (technically correct or not). Merely saying "you plagiarised this" apparently doesn't evoke "oh, maybe I shouldn't have done that" in all of our visitors.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition The trouble is not so much the ownership aspect of it (we all "adopt" code from Stack Overflow into our code bases without attribution, that's fine), it's the act of creating duplicate content on the site. Calling it plagiarism or stealing is missing the point, unnecessarily confrontational and can be left entirely out of the discussion of why one shouldn't willingly create duplicate content on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Gimby: _"we all 'adopt' code from Stack Overflow into our code bases without attribution, that's fine"_ It really isn't "fine"